# Фильтрация с преобразованием объекта в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Как преобразовать с помощью JS Объект со вложенными массивами

```
{
    "0" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 13000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 1 ],
            "1" : [ 0 ],
            "2" : [ 0 ]
        }
    },
    "1" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 41000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 0 ],
            "1" : [ 1 ],
            "2" : [ 0 ]
        }
    },
    "2" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 27000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 1 ],
            "1" : [ 0 ],
            "2" : [ 1 ]
        }
    }
}
```

в Массив такого вида:

```
[
  {
    "groups" : 0,
    "breakpoint" : [
      13000,
      27000
    ]
  }
  {
    "groups" : 1,
    "breakpoint" : [
      41000
    ]
  }
  {
    "groups" : 2,
    "breakpoint" : [
      27000
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Стоит, наверное, подробнее объяснить принцип перегруппировки. Пока он не совсем очевиден.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, выглядит как из группировки по breakpoint сделать группировку по groups

Comment: То есть `[ 1 ]` означает группа включает брекпоинт, а `[ 0 ]` — не включает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имена групп всегда являются последовательными числами от 0 и выше, можно так:

```js
const breakpoints = {
    "0" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 13000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 1 ],
            "1" : [ 0 ],
            "2" : [ 0 ]
        }
    },
    "1" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 41000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 0 ],
            "1" : [ 1 ],
            "2" : [ 0 ]
        }
    },
    "2" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 27000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 1 ],
            "1" : [ 0 ],
            "2" : [ 1 ]
        }
    }
};

const groups = Object.values(breakpoints).reduce(
  (acc, { breakpoint, groups }) => {
    for (const [group, [hasBreakpoint]] of Object.entries(groups)) {
      if (!acc[group]) acc[group] = { groups: group, breakpoint: [] };
      if (hasBreakpoint) acc[group].breakpoint.push(breakpoint);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [],
);

console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data={
    "0" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 13000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 1 ],
            "1" : [ 0 ],
            "2" : [ 0 ]
        }
    },
    "1" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 41000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 0 ],
            "1" : [ 1 ],
            "2" : [ 0 ]
        }
    },
    "2" :   {
        "breakpoint" : 27000,
        "groups" :      {
            "0" : [ 1 ],
            "1" : [ 0 ],
            "2" : [ 1 ]
        }
    }
};
const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc,item)=>{
  Object.entries(item[1].groups).map(g=>{
    if(!acc[g[0]]) acc[g[0]] = {"groups" : parseInt(g[0]),breakpoint:[]};
    if(g[1][0]===1) acc[g[0]].breakpoint.push(item[1].breakpoint);
  })
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Object.values` вернет массив значений сразу